# Remove Web Deploy from a VS2010 .Net 4 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teamcity, web-deployment

I am currently setting up a TeamCity server (Windows 2012 R2 - for which I can't find a Windows SDK), one of the projects is failing with the following error

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found.

I understand that it is looking for files which will be put in place if I install VS2010 on the machine, moreover the VS2010 project does not utilise Web Deploy at all, I also know that If I could find a Windows SDK for Windows 2012 R2 then I wouldn't have to install VS2010.

The question then is can I totally remove Web Deploy from the VS2010 project?

I've tried the obvious of removing the line

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

from the *.proj file, however upon reopening / reloading the project this causes VS2010 to think that it's an older project which needs to be updated and presents the wizard to do so.